# Como relacionar tabelas no MySQL para mais de uma entidade?

Tags: mysql, modelagem

Como posso relacionar uma tabela(entidade) com mais de uma entidade no banco MySQL? seguindo o seguinte exemplo...

Tenho as tabelas: `fornecedores`, `clientes` e `telefones`.

- Os `fornecedores`, podem ter mais de um telefone.
- Os `clientes`, também podem ter mais do que um telefone.

Para resolver esse problema, eu criei um relacionamento `N:N`, onde um `fornecedor` pode ter vários `telefones`, porém um telefone não pertence a vários `fornecedores`. Isso aí, igual para `clientes`, onde um cliente pode ter vários `telefones`, mas um telefone não pertence a vários `clientes`.

Com esse relacionamento N:N, criou-se uma tabela intermediária entre `fornecedores` e `telefones`, e também entre `clientes` e `telefones`.

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema, sem precisar ter uma tabela de telefone para relacionar com `fornecedores`, e mais outra tabela telefone para relacionar com `clientes`? sem que seja `N:N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não creio que você esteja certo quanto a relação `N:N` segundo o que você descreveu.
Até onde eu sei, a relação entre:

- clientes e telefones:  one-to-many
- fornecedores e telefones: one-to-many
- telefones e clientes: many-to-one
- telefones e fornecedores: many-to-one

Também, do ponto pragmático, eu acho que criar uma tabela tal como `telefones_clientes` e `telefones_forncedores` não é uma boa ideia, desde que há uma redundância à princípio desnecessária. Dito isso, penso que uma abordagem mais sensata e prática seria algo como:

[image: Esquema da base de dados]

É claro, não há uma chave estrangeira explícita e formalmente definida na tabela telefones. No entanto o conceito ainda permanece, uma vez que o campo `telefones.quem` deve apontar para uma chave primária da tabela **fornecedores** ou **clientes**.

```
FORNECEDORES |           +-------------+         | CLIENTES    |
------------ +           | TELEFONES   |         +-------------+
 id          | ____      +-------------+     ___ | id          |
------------ +      \    | id          |    /    +-------------+
 nome        |       \___+-------------+___/     | nome        |
------------ +           | quem        |         +-------------+
                         +-------------+
                         | is_cliente  | -- é cliente (1) ou fornecedor (2)? --
                         +-------------+
                         | telefone    |
                         +-------------+
```

Com o esquema acima você tem `telefones.quem` referenciando um `clientes.id` ou `forncedores.id`. Isso mesmo facilita uma consulta SQL por somente telefones de clientes ou fornecedores através do campo `telefones.is_cliente`.

Em resumo você teria:

**Prós**

- Flexibilidade (fácil de alterar e gerenciar).
- Apenas uma tabela com telefones, menos *JOINS*, mais fácil de consultar (neste caso);
- Esquema  e estrutura limpa e que faz sentido;

**Contras:**

- Não há explícita restrição quanto a integridade relacional;
- Opções/ações de Foreign Key tal como *ON DELETE CASCADE* não é disponível;
- Uma vez que você deletar um registro cliente ou fornecedor, você terá de manualmente deletar suas referências na tabela `telefones`, se isso é importante;

---

Um famoso "mantra" do Python ([Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) vem a calhar aqui:

> ... *practicality beats purity*.

Comment: hehe... bacana kra. Acho que vou trabalhar de forma polimórfica mesmo. Inclusive, como o sistema vai ser em PHP e que vou usar o Laravel, ele já tem por padrão no ORM dele, da forma de trabalhar assim como você explicou.

Comment: @paulomartinhago Eu estou certo que este é o caminho melhor e menos doloroso (dadas as circunstâncias), pode apostar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Não existe motivo para não ter duas tabelas, o seu cliente também será o seu fornecedor ou vice-versa? Acredito que não, e mesmo que isso aconteça eu não acho que aconteceria mais de 10 vezes...

Partindo desse principio então o ideal é ter duas tabelas, até para organizar os planos de acesso no banco de dados.

Soluções como:

```js
TelefoneRelacionado
ID_TELEFONE   
ID_CLIENTEouFORNECEDOR
```

ou então

```js
TelefoneRelacionado  
ID_TELEFONE  
ID_CLIENTE (pode null) 
ID_FORNECEDOR (pode null)
```

alem de complicar a vida da manutenção pode deixar o banco de dados maluco nos planos de acesso, no caso o exemplo um não vai ter chave estrangeira ligando as tabelas.

Outro ponto é que você não vai replicar dados usando duas tabelas, não terá um único número de telefone gravado nas duas tabelas, pelo fato citado no inicio de não terem muitos clientes que sejam fornecedores e vice-versa.

Essa seria a minha resposta a sua pergunta. As duas soluções acima são maneiras de se fazer isso, não são elegantes e eu ouso dizer que são ruins. (meu ponto de vista apenas)

Se o sistema é tão grande ao ponto de causar uma preocupação dessa então vale pensar em quanto isso estiver rodando e cheio de dados, como os SQLs serão feitos.

Comment: As tabelas que informei, são somente como exemplo, são fictícias. A aplicação real é com outros tipos de tabelas, mas que tem a mesma resolução do problema citado. No sistema real, eu tenho a tabela clientes e telefones, porém a tabela "fornecedores" que citei no exemplo, seria uma tabela chamada "entidades", pois é um sistema de licitações. Só não informei "entidades" no exemplo para não confundir com ER.

Comment: @paulomartinhago entendi, mas mesmo assim acho que o que eu falei se aplica, não fugiria de um bom e velho banco relacional não.

Comment: Com certeza. Estou vendo para usar uma relação polimórfica mesmo.

Comment: Sim, é quase uma herança que você quer fazer, se cliente é uma entidade você pode relacionar so entidade com telefone, mas mesmo assim, é bom pensar bem antes de separar as tabelas de entidade de cliente e fornecedor, no final se ganha tão pouco com economia de espaço e pode ficar muito complicado o código.

Comment: Isso é fato, por isso sempre penso bem antes de fazer algum tipo de modelagem, até mesmo porque não é meu forte.

Answer (score 1):

Está fazendo uma coisa errada, o correto é você relacionar a pessoa / usuário (ou sua entidade) aos telefones, e a sua entidade você relaciona ao perfil dele, mesmo que ele já tenha uma entidade, você cria um controle (fonecedor ou cliente). Dessa maneira você consegue incluir dinamicamente fornecedor, distribuidor, revendedor, cliente, vendedor e por aí vai...

1. entidade->telefones 1:N (one-to-many);
2. entidade->perfil 1:N (one-to-many);
3. perfil->entidade N:N (many-to-many);

**PS:** Eu não recomendo utilizar regras automáticas de exclusão pelas chaves estrangeiras, pois isso pode afetar em perda de dados, minha sugestão é, faça isso pelo código, é mais seguro e tira a responsabilidade do banco, passando a responsabilidade para o sistema.

Comment: Não, Ivan. O fornecedor e o cliente, não é especificamente uma pessoa, e sim uma empresa. Esse exemplo foi somente para especificar o meu problema. Como o sistema real é de licitações, eu tenho um modelo chamado entidades, e outro modelo chamado clientes, onde as entidades(prefeituras, por exemplo) lançam licitações, e os clientes(empresas) recebem as licitações conforme os CNAE's. Por isso a necessidade de ligar as entidades e os clientes a telefones, podendo ter mais do que um.

Comment: Que seja, você até pode fazer isso com entidades, e tratá-las como usuários distintos, a regra a ser aplicada é a mesma. Se vc tem 2 ou 3 entidades (pode ser traduzido para usuários), é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Sim, entendi sua lógica. Inclusive, valeu pela dica sobre exclusão =)